# Ldap query in AD for user that have at least one group?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

(Sorry for my terrible English)
I need to do a search with Ldap in AD that finds users who have at least one group, any suggestion?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up as simple as it can be.

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=*))
```

The reason is, `memberOf` LDAP filter does not count for "primary" group membership, which for AD DS is normally "Domain Users" and all users are normally members of that group. Therefore, if `memberOf` is populated, then the user is a member of any other group but primary.

Comment: The only caveat is that domain local groups do not show up in `memberOf`. But if you only have one domain, that may not be an issue for you.